# Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server, Failed to register URL, Access is denied

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, port, iis-express

Some web projects are causing me problems while others work fine. I decided to focus on one of the problematic ones.
I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7. I think I'm running it as administrator, the window title says `PROJECT NAME - Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator)`.

When I try to run the project I get a popup saying:

> Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server.
>
> Failed to register URL "http://localhost:62940/" for site "SITE NAME"
>       application "/". Error description: Access is denied. (0x80070005).

This does not seem [entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454751/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error) [uncommon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188547/running-iis-express-without-administrator-rights) but I have tried many of the suggestions without luck:

1. Deleted `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\`, tried to run.
2. `netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:62940/ user=everyone`, rebooted and tried to run. (Actually `user=Alla` since Swedish Windows).
3. `netsh http delete urlacl url=http://localhost:62940/`, rebooted and changed from `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62940:localhost />` to `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62940:/>` in `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` and tried to run. (It did changed the error message to say `... URL "http://*:62940/" ...`.
4. Reinstalled IIS 8.0 Express
5. Reinstalled Visual Studio 2013

I'm at my wit's end, what am I doing wrong?

If I change the port of the project (e.g. to 55555) it starts... This is not a desirable solution since these projects are worked on by several people. Maybe the port is blocked by something else? If so, is there an easy way to check by what?

Port 62940 seems to be free. Running `netstat` does not show any application listening to it. Something else must be wrong.

I tried starting the project today after not touching it for a few months. It worked but I don't know why.

Comment: Run `netstat -aon | findstr` to see if another application also monitors port 62940. If so, you cannot monitor that port but have to switch to another port. Don't change applicationHost.config or `netsh http` when they are obviously not the cause.

Comment: I ran `netstat` as suggested. No application seems to be monitoring port 62940. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: Rebooting worked for me.

Comment: Restarting VS solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 114):

Yeah, I agree, top answers are really pro solutions. Here is one for intermediates:

**Solution Explorer**

1. **Right click** on project select **Unload project**
2. Again Right click and select **Edit ProjectName.csproj**
3. Remove these 3 lines

```xml
<DevelopmentServerPort>0</DevelopmentServerPort>
<DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
<IISUrl>http://localhost:62940/</IISUrl>
```

4. Save and reload the project, and you are good to go.

Comment: Anybody else who gets here, I had to delete in `.csproj`, and also `.csproj.user`.  FWIW

Answer (score 104):

I solved the error by changing the **port** for the project.

I did the following steps:

1 - Right click on the project.
2 - Go to properties.
3 - Go to *Server* tab.
4 - On tab section, change the project URL for other port, like 8080 or 3000.

Good luck!

Comment: This is not working in 2022 as the option is not available any more as of June 2023

Answer (score 98):

This is the only solution I found

```
net stop winnat

net start winnat
```

[Thanks to Matt](https://mattferderer.com/visual-studio-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server)

Comment: This worked for me in Nov 2022 using Win10! Thanks

Comment: Worked for me in Jan 2023

Comment: Worked for me in March 2023. VS 2022 Windows 10.

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 11.  June 2023.

Comment: NOPE: "The Windows NAT Driver service is not started"

Comment: the only sulotion that worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Worked for me in Dec 2023, thanks!

Comment: Worked for me in Dec 2023 on a NET Core Web API project using IIS Express. This is the Windows Network Address Translation (NAT) service. By doing this, you effectively release and then reassign the ports that the NAT service is managing, which can clear up any port conflicts without having to identify and terminate specific processes. Rebooting the machine didn't work and I **couldn't** kill the PID that was responsible either.

Comment: Finally! Worked for me in January 2024, VS2022 on Windows 10. None of the other solutions here or elsewhere worked.

Answer (score 72):

try (as elevated administrator)

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://*:62940/
```

Comment: This helped, but in my case was not sufficient. I also had to add the proper url back using `netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:62940/ user=Everyone`

Comment: In my case - no one using the port in this list...

Answer (score 66):

The ideal way to sort this out is to use the IIS Express tray icon to stop the web site that is causing the problem. To do this, click the little upward-pointing arrow in the right-hand end of the task bar and right-click the IIS Express icon. This will pop up a small window showing you the web sites that IIS Express is currently running...

[image: IIS Express pop up]

If you click on one of the items under "View Sites" you have the option to stop that site. Or, you can click the Exit item at the bottom of the window to stop all web sites.

That should enable you to debug in Visual Studio. When you start debugging again, IIS Express will automatically restart the web site, and should be able to allocate the port.

If that fails, you have to do it the dirty way. Open Windows Task Manager and kill the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe*32` process, then you can run the project fine. Note that this will kill IIS Express completely, meaning that all web sites will stop, so you'll have to restart each one in VS if you want to debug any others. Try the pop-up icon method first tough as it's cleaner and safer.

Don't know if this answers your issue, but it works for me.

**Update** Thanks to JasonCoder (see comment below) for adding that on Win10, the process is `Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost.exe`

Answer (score 59):

When using Visual Studio 2015 the solution can be a bit different to the previous answers.  VS2015 creates a hidden folder .vs under the same folder as your solution file.  Under this is a config folder containing applicationhost.config.  Deleting this file (or the entire .vs folder) then starting VS2015 to recreate it can fix this error.

Answer (score 59):

I got the same issue when running my application from Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10. 
After some time googling and trying various proposed solutions without success, I determined that the "Access Denied" error was a result of the port number my application uses (50403) falling in an "excluded port range".

You can view the excluded port ranges with the following command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

After some more time googling I found that the two most likely culprits that create these exclusion ranges are Docker and Hyper-V. Docker was not installed on my computer but Hyper-V was.

**My Solution**

1. Disable Hyper-V: Control Panel-> Programs and Features-> Turn Windows features on or off. Untick Hyper-V
2. Restart the computer.
3. Add the port you are using to the port exclusion range: `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=50403 numberofports=1 store=persistent`
4. Reenable Hyper-V
5. Restart the computer

I added the port I am using to the exclusion list to ensure that I won't get this problem again after reenabling Hyper-V. After Step 4 and 5 when I viewed the excluded port range I can see that Hyper-V reserved a port range starting with the next port after my port.

[image: Excluded Port Range]

My application now worked perfectly!

Comment: Why would adding the port to the exclusion list help? Does it not mean TCP is not longer able to use the port?

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown I think you need the port exclusion in place when re-enabling Hyper-V. Once Hyper-V has grabbed other ports the exclusion can be removed.

Comment: This did work for me when a number of the other suggestions did not. I should note, I have not (yet) reenabled HyperV -- don't need it at the moment.

Answer (score 57):

Got this error as well lately.  Tried all the above fixes, but none worked.

To disable it, type `services.msc` in command prompt, then right click and disable **Internet Connection Sharing**. I edited the properties of it as well to disable at startup. Mine looks like so now: [services capture screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJSrP.png).

Comment: I am using VS2022 and this answer helped me. Tried few other solutions but only this one worked. Quick and easy fix.

Comment: I was not able to stop this service.  I believe that's because I had Hyper-V services running, and those services require ICS.  If you're having this problem *and* need Hyper-V, see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59611632/654199).

Answer (score 34):

This happened with me when I was trying to **access my site from a remote location**:

At first, applicationhost.config (VS2015) contained the standard:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:64376:localhost" />
```

In order to access my site from a remote location within the network, I added (step 1):

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:64376:192.168.10.132" />
```

Then, I entered into CMD with Admin rights (step 2):

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:64376/ user=Everyone
```

As step 3, I added it a rule to the firewall.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”IISExpressWeb” dir=in protocol=tcp localport=64376 profile=private,domain remoteip=localsubnet action=allow
```

Then, I got this error when trying to run the solution again.

**Solution:** I seemed to have done everything right, but it did not work until I ran `netsh` also for the **existing localhost rule**:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:64376/ user=Everyone
```

Now, it works again.

Answer (score 27):

I just had a similar issue. I'm not totally sure how to describe the actual fault but it seems like the hostname in the reservation is incorrect. Try this in an elevated command prompt...

`netsh http delete urlacl url=http://localhost:62940/`

... then ...

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:62940/ user=everyone`

and restart your site. It should work.

Answer (score 26):

I ran into this same error message, but it looks like it was produced from IIS Express.  [This article](http://programmingflow.com/2015/08/28/solved-iis-express-failed-to-register-url---access-is-denied.html) helped me resolve it

TL;DR

Run the following command from an Administrative command prompt:

```
> netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::
```

Answer (score 23):

After trying a number of suggested solutions without success I just rebooted my PC. After that the problem didn't occur anymore.

Answer (score 15):

I ended up with cleaning the project file (csproj) and the applicationhost.config (iis express) with all entries regarding iis express configuration. After that, it worked.

Comment: Cleaning out the `applicationhost.config` file worked for me. I just deleted all of the `<site>` entries in it.
`C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

Answer (score 13):

If you're having this after installing Visual Studio 2015 and you can see Error messages in System event log such as this: `Unable to bind to the underlying transport for [::]:{your_port}. . The IP Listen-Only list may contain a reference ...` then you might be missing a registry entry.

Run this under administrative command prompt: `netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::` to fix it.

I found the solution described in detail [here](http://programmingflow.com/2015/08/28/solved-iis-express-failed-to-register-url---access-is-denied.html)

Answer (score 10):

After all of the steps listed here failed for me I got it working by running VS2015 as administrator.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me on Windows 10 and VS 2013.
Apparently there is a maximum port number IIS Express handles. 
Ports above 62546 don't work for me.

Comment: I can't be sure if or what the max is. However, I was suffering from this error. I then deleted `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress` and edited my .csproj file, moving from port 63584 to 61111. 

After reloading, my project started just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Got the same issue where IIS express complained about *http://localhost:50418/* and none of above solutions worked for me..

Went to *projektFolder --> .vs --> config --> applicationhost.xml*

In the tag `<sites>` I found that my web app had two bindnings registered.

```
<site name="myApp.Web" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\git\myApp\myApp.Web" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44332:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50418:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Removing the binding pointing to *:50418:localhost solved the issue.

Using VS2017 and IISExpress v10.

Comment: Actually there are always two bindings, because those are for different protocols. I always worked with these without problem, it uses the port according to the used protocol. It is not correct to remove those... The problem is somewhere else...

Comment: This worked for me, I had to remove some rogue bindings that where injected at this location. I kept the two default bindings. If you use VS2019 or VS2022, you find this file here: `$(solutionDir)\.vs\{projectName}\config\applicationhost.config`. If you use IIS Express stand alone, you find the file here: `%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config`.

Answer (score 4):

The error can be solved if you just restart Visual Studio. It has the same effect as restarting the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe*32 process.

Answer (score 3):

My issue turned out to be that I had SSL Enabled on the project settings. I simply disabled this because I did not require SSL for running the project locally.

In Visual Studio 2015:

- Select the project in the Solution Explorer.
- In the Properties window set SSL Enabled to False.
- I was able to run the project.

In my situation I was getting an error about port 443 in use because this was the port set on the SSL URL for the project.

Comment: I had the inverse of this, I actually needed to enable SSL on my project. Good to see I'm not the only person who saw this error due to SSL.

Comment: I had to do this to set it to using ssl and then back to not (my app is not supposed to use ssl)

Answer (score 3):

Running `netstat -abn` I noticed that the software "Duet Display" was reserving thousands of ports in the ~51000 range.

Closing it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this error my be another Visual Studio version running on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the project "Properties" => "Web", and on the "Servers" section change the port to something else that is not used in and save it. You will be asked to created a virtual directory and click "Yes". Now run the project and it will work now.

Comment: This is the exact same answer as Francisco wrote 3 weeks prior.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it worked at first and after a while stopped working and IIS Express reported that the port was in use.
`netstat -ab` showed that Chrome was using the port. After I quit Chrome, it started working again.
I am not sure however, why Chrome would occupy that port.

Comment: This worked for me. I was using Browse With and switching between Firefox and Chrome without running the debugger. Something must have gotten hung up in the process. (Win7/VS2015)

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on Windows 7 and VS  2013 while viewing a project on the browser after build. I only had to close the browser "Chrome" then made sure that the port is not in use in my Network Activities using some utility (Kaspersky) then tried again and worked without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2015:

- Find your startup page in your project (eg: mypage.aspx) , and right
  click on it.
- Click on Set as Start Page.
- Right click on the project.
- Click on Properties.
- Click on the Web Tab on the left.
- In Project URL, enter a different port, such as:  http://localhost:1234/
- In Start Action, select Specific Page: mypage.aspx or select Specific URL: http://localhost:1234/mypage.aspx?myparam=xxx

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by killing all instances of iexplorer and iexplorer*32.  It looks like Internet Explorer was still in memory holding the port open even though the application window was closed.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with JetBrains Rider, specifically for port 80 and 90 bit it was working with other ports as well as visual studio.

after running as admin this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**In Visual Studio 2019**
Just remove Debug profile and create new one Do the Trick

1. Go to Project properties In debug tab
2. try first Changing ports Web Server Settings
3. if Changing ports not worked then Remove Debug Profile and Create new One-Warning Make Sure You Know Previous Settings

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is disabling all other network adapters, except the one I'm currently using. The event in event viewer was:
`Unable to bind to the underlying transport for [::]:50064. The IP Listen-Only list may contain a reference to an interface which may not exist on this machine.  The data field contains the error number.`

Since I have VMware Workstation, Docker (and thus Hyper V) some VPN clients, I have a lot of network interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

For me, what solved it was disconnecting from the VPN (we're using FortiClient)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like everybody has own problem
Just sharing what I did to fix this problem in VS2015 (Windows 8.1), my solution has 6 web sites (not web apps)

1. Open your solution file *.sln
2. Change in your solution file string
   VWDPort = "34781" (make it unique in your solution if you have more
   that 1 web site, I made +2) in notepad.

See sample solution file ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties):

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "BOSTONBEANCOFFEE.COM", "Source_WebOfficeV4\BOSTONBEANCOFFEE.COM", "{5106A8F5-401B-4907-981C-F37784DC4E9D}"
ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
    SccProjectName = ""$/PrismRMSystem/VS2012/WebOfficeV4.root/WebOfficeV4", IPYHAAAA"
    SccAuxPath = ""
    SccLocalPath = "..\.."
    SccProvider = "MSSCCI:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe"
    TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"
    ProjectReferences = "{04e527c3-bac6-4082-9d39-aad8771b368e}|YBTools.dll;{5d52eaec-42fb-4313-83b8-69e2f55ebf14}|AuthorizeNet.dll;{d8408f53-8f1e-4a71-8b05-76023b09b716}|AuthorizeNet.Helpers.dll;{77ebd08a-de0f-4793-b436-fad6980863e6}|WEBCUSTCONTROLS.dll;"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/BOSTONBEANCOFFEE.COM"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "Source_WebOfficeV4\BOSTONBEANCOFFEE.COM\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\BOSTONBEANCOFFEE.COM\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.KeyFile = "Key\StrongKey.snk"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.DelaySign = "false"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers = "false"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/BOSTONBEANCOFFEE.COM"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "Source_WebOfficeV4\BOSTONBEANCOFFEE.COM\"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\BOSTONBEANCOFFEE.COM\"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.KeyFile = "Key\StrongKey.snk"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.DelaySign = "false"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers = "false"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"      
    VWDPort = "34781"
    SlnRelativePath = "Source_WebOfficeV4\BOSTONBEANCOFFEE.COM\"
EndProjectSection
```

In my case, I tried to change URL from project properties, restart VS, reboot computer, nothing helped me only this SLN file manipulation fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem was entirely related to a broken install of Oracle ODP tools for VS. I uninstalled and reinstalled and everything was working again.

Answer (score 1):

I write it for information.

Delete the file in the project.

After Clean>Build>Proje Start

Answer (score 1):

And in my case, it turned out that I didn't have IIS enabled in Control Panel under Windows Features.
[Reference Image, since SO won't let me upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5GPK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In VS2017. I had to edit my .sln file and had to update the **VWDPort = "5010"** setting. None of the other solutions posted here worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the setting **Override application root URL** checked, on the `Properties`->`Web` tab. I was using that previously when I was running VS as an administrator, but now that I'm running it in a non-admin account, it causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me but the solution here https://forums.asp.net/t/1979442.aspx?Cannot+change+the+project+URL+in+project+properties did.

Once I had the solution file open in notepad I did a find and replace of the port that was causing the problem, saved it and reopened the solution in visual studio. The first time I picked a port number that was only 1 off from the one that was causing my problem and I still got the same error. When I changed to a port that something like 10,000 off it worked. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I also read the answers and comments and tried some solutions from this thread.

Then a Googled a little more and this worked for me

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/iis-express-failed-to-register-url-access-is-denied

Didn't comment on no one's answer because I didn't read whats written here, so it needed a new answer post.
There's answers here that talk about **netsh wlan** stuff, but I didn't see exactly this solution.
If some one wrote the exact same solution **please tell me** so I can comment there and remove this.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same with VS2019 occasionally.

The general problem is that the port is already taken or not usable, and there's a lot of possible reasons for that, resulting in lots of different answers here.

I want to add what helped me: The problem was just temporary and I tried again *without changing anything* and it just worked. So I just propose to test this first, because it is the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Visual Studio 2019, After trying a lot of suggestions that failed to work (including changing the port number etc) I solved my problem by deleting a file that was generated on my project's root folder called "*debug*". As soon as this file was deleted everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

Folks, i read all the comments ranging between 2 page views and still none helped my situation. Although, some helped to a little extent. Finally this is what helped solved my situation and i assume it may be the case for someone else too.

I have a docker Desktop as well in my laptop and I was running some in Docker. Then, i opened my VS and wanted to debug my specific app. Although with VS 2019 and the web api is configured to use Https port, the http port was causing this issue. After attempting all the steps that were mentioned in the answers, i went with my gut

1. to stop and kill my docker desktop app.
2. Then stopped the running IIS Express.
3. Just simply pressed F5 (to debug) and voila!

So, there are various reasons to this issue and it depends on individual's machine status and apps they have.

I tried deleting the .vs folder, removing the IISExpress folder in user profile's documents folder, but then, my Docker app I guess must be taking over the remaining IP addresses if my VS is not using them.

So, kindly check any other apps that may take/consume some span or range of IPs and try kill them. In my case, I started Docker again after running my VS and things are going as expected so far!

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the answers above.
It only worked when I stopped the Windows Service ICS (Internet Connection Sharing).

Comment: This approach really helped me out. 

For those looking to apply this solution using PowerShell (run as admin), here's the script I ended up using:

**First, get the ProcessId**:
`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE 'SharedAccess'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessId`

**Then, use the ProcessId you obtained in the following command (replace [pidid] with the actual ProcessId):**
`taskkill /pid [pidid] /f`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, running VS as an Administrator solved the problem. But the weirdest part I already checked the "run as administrator" setting on the shortcut which seemed not working.

Looks like we need to explicitly click "run as administrator" choice from the shortcuts context menu

[image]

[image]