# How to run existing ASP.NET C# Web App Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, visual-studio-2019

Need to run an existing C# ASP.NET project. The project contains following:

1. LinkWeb.sln
2. LinkWeb.csproj
3. clsApp.cs
4. Link.html
5. Database.aspx.cs
6. Server.aspx.cs
7. Web.config
8. Few more files

Using visual studio 2019, opened the solution file. Tried to build by clicking "ISS Express (Microsoft Edge)". The app does run, but gives an error "unable to communicate to server" within browser. Completely new in .NET development. Please, let me know the **steps to build the code** so that the html file could connect to server (assuming i am unable to run the server).

Comment: Project contains .sln file ? You are not mistaken?

Comment: First, you need to confirm which page is your first page. After this, you right click Server.apx view in browser. or you can set as start page. Besides, I also find the similar problem [ASP.NET 5 MVC: unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675747/asp-net-5-mvc-unable-to-connect-to-web-server-iis-express).

Comment: Tried the above, but again landed up in error "cannot list the directory files."

Comment: set any .aspx page as startup page and in page load method of that page,put debugger and run the application.In this way by pressing F10 you can watch line by line execution of your code and on certain line ,if you got error.fix that issue then

Comment: Please note that, its an existing code which already works. I just need to run the same. No need to go for debugging.