# Visual Studio 2015. Failed to register URL for site access is denied IIS Express. Access denied 0x80070005

Tags: ssl, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, localhost, iis-express

I enabled SSL in Visual Studio 2015 in order to implement *Facebook* and *Google* login locally.

I changed the *project URL* in the *Web tab* of the project's properties to *https://localhost:44300/* and decorated the controller with the ***RequireHttps*** attribute - [ref @msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute(v=vs.100).aspx).

Everything worked fine locally.

I reverted settings to HTTP to test something else and that caused me a problem when I tried to get back to HTTPS.

I found [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502327/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-failed-to-register-url-access-is-d) question and tried almost every suggested solution.

**Error detail:**

> Failed to register URL "*url*" for site "*site*" application "*path*".
>   Error description: Access is denied. (0x80070005).

Comment: You should extract the answer part to an answer and accept it. That's the format of an FAQ if you read other posts.

Answer (score 12):

I had to issue this command in DOS to solve the problem in VS 2015:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://{ip_addr}:{port}/ user=everyone
```

Strangely this was only needed when I moved the project to a different PC. On the original PC I didn't need it.

Comment: Note that *, 127.0.0.1 and localhost are treated as separate... 
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://*:10001/
netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:10001/ user=everyone

netsh http delete urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:10001/
netsh http add urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:10001/ user=everyone

netsh http delete urlacl url=http://localhost:10001/
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:10001/ user=everyone

Comment: You can also add only your user to ACL with `user=<your Windows user name>` instead of `everyone`.

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Can anyone elaborate on why this worked?

Answer (score 3):

Turned out this very answer [on the same question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162151/6146939) by [Cayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2769361/cayne) led me to the solution.

The port change didn't work because applicationhost.config file, located in .vs folder specific for VS2015, kept bindings combo of old port for Http and Https as a default setting. No matter how many times did I change port to something else while trying with Http (only got clogged with mass of new web site bindings in the config file) as soon as I wanted to switch back to SSL it ended up with the first bindings combo. The port it complained about that can't be registered any more.

Once I deleted that first bindings combo everything was fine.

I hope this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *C:\Users{username}\Documents\IISExpress\config* and open the *applicationhost.config* file.

Search for the `<sites>` tag in the document. You will see some lines similar to the following.

```
<site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Replace the line `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:localhost" />` as follows.

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:{required_port_number}:*" />
```

I think you can even remove the `*` marks in `bindingInformation`.

Then restart IIS Server (remove all IIS server related operations using *Task Manager* and go to *C:\Program Files\IIS Express* folder and run *iisexpress.exe*: you might need to *Run as Administrator*).

A console will open and if all went well, following lines will be displayed.

`Successfully registered URL "http://*:{required_port_number}/" for site "Website1" application "/"
...`

Also check in browser whether the required URL works now.

[Here's a very useful resource...](http://www.ryadel.com/en/iis-express-allow-external-requests-remote-clients-devices/)

Comment: FYI Visual Studio will now create an iis express config file in folder .vs/$solution/config, and pass that file as an argument when starting the web site.