# unable to launch IIS Express webserver and tried all options available in stackoverflow

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2012

hi guyz I am using visual studio 2012 IIS 8.5 and when I run the webpages I will get the error like

**Unable to launchIIS web server express failed to register URL http://localhost:64286 for site webapplication application "/" Error :access is denied**

I have tried all solutions available in stackover flow and online except changing port number as I couldn't find the option under properties->web-> dynamic ports  OR any other option to change port number. Till morning it was working fine problem started when I restarted the system and since then I was unable to solve this

I have made visual studio run as ADMINISTRATOR and tried rebooting the system
I can't find the path to change port number so, no luck doing that.
I don't understand all if sudden why it is behaving like this.same code was running fine since 2 months and since morning it stops running with this ugly error 
Please help me I have project viva tomorrow
TIA

Comment: Have you copied the project and running both the projects simultaneously? This Error occurs if your port is already is in use. Try changing the port number and run again.

Comment: This post has many suggested solutions those may help,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502327/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-failed-to-register-url-access-is-d

Comment: @AnupSharma No i haven't running two projects simultaneously.

Comment: Did you try restarting Computer or Resetting Studio?

Comment: @Adil I ahve already viewed that page but, no solution had worked for me and to change the port number I cant find the options mentioned there. I am using MSVS 2012 the options are not there

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an aggresive firewall that blocks the port or program? What happens if you go to http://localhost:64286?

Comment: This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 64286