# Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server. Failed to register URL. Access is denied

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Does anyone know why this happens? When i open visual studio without administrator mode i get the error "Unable to connect to web ser 'IIS Express'. I had this error before and i fixed changing the port number, but now doesn't work.

It's worth to mention that in other Api's i can run ISS Server normally, i just have this thing with administrator mode only in one project.

Thanks!

Comment: I just realised that the server ir runnig and i can use the api, but i doesn't open um debug mode

Comment: @haldo i've tryed that and doesn't solve my problem :/

Comment: I started getting this problem after using a porgram called JexusManager

Comment: Hows about this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54360122/9665021 ?

Comment: @haldo i dont have those 3 lines in .csproj file

Comment: Try to [disable SSL like the pic](https://i.imgur.com/XHPUz9f.png). Then retry to run your app, and tell us the result.

Comment: @JasonPan I've tried that, in fact SSL was disable all the time. I tried pretty much everything i found for like 3h and ended up creating a new project and copied all the classes to that new one. Btw i used the same ports that i was trying on the old project and worked, i really dont know what happened on the old project files

Comment: Try to delete `.vs ` folder, then reopen your project and run. Hope it useful to you.

Comment: @JasonPan I tried also that before, didn't work. After creating a new project i had no more problems, but thanks anymay.